# virtualbox snapshot - is it a safe back-up if I want to over-write (dd to) sda1?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, chroot, snapshot

I want to do some testing useing chroot to overwrite sda1 (my main partition) in a ubuntu VM. Is taking a virtualbox snapshot a safe way to create a backup?

i.e. in the VM I want to create a chroot environment in:

`/tmp/mytestenv/...`

Then (only in the VM) I want to dd over my `/dev/sda1` to simulate writing a new image over it. Such that when I reboot the system will not load (that is the test for now). However when I do this test I will want to revert back to the working VM pre-overwriting sda1.

So my question is, will a virtualbox snapshot be good enough to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Well.... in case anyone was interested - the answer is yes! (I just tried it after making a complete backup of my VM)... nice job Virtualbox :)